# I would like to correct this error flutter bloc constant

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

The default value of an optional parameter must be constant

```
abstract class LoginState {
    const LoginState();
}

class LoginInitialState extends LoginState {
    const LoginInitialState();
}

class LoginFinalState extends LoginState {
    final Usuario usuario;
    const LoginFinalState({this.usuario = const Usuario()});
    //The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all the `const` keyword, if you don't want do this, just add a cont constructor to `Usuario` like below

```
class Usuario {
  const Usuario();
}
```